# Visual Studio Code editor in Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

After using the following configuration in Terminal for VSCode

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

and trying to commit by the following command

```
git commit
```

gives me the following message

> code --wait: code: command not found
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Any idea why doesn't open the editor?

Comment: Can you use the command `code` anywhere in the terminal?

Comment: when i use the command code gives me the following message -bash: code: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)

- Launch VS Code.
- Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type 'shell
  command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH
  command.

[image]